# How can I generate a POJO file for this JSON response for auto-deserialization?

Tags: android, json, serialization, gson, deserialization

I get a JSON response like this from a server:

```
{
    "name_1": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": 1,
            "value": "25"
        },
         {
            "id": 2,
            "type": 2,
            "value": "25"
        }
    ],
    "name_2": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "type": 1,
            "value": "25"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "type": 4,
            "value": "25"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "type": 4,
            "value": "25"
        }
    ],
     "name_3": [
        {
            "id": 8,
            "type": 1,
            "value": "25"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I generate a POJO file for this in order to use it for auto-deserializing with retrofit?
I tried www.jsonschema2pojo.org, but it wants to create a new class for each JSON object, which is a list (name_1, name_2, name_3), but the count of "name_X" arrays could be different, as well as ther names.

So how can I create a POJO java class for auto-deserializing with GsonConverterFactory in retrofit?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Take a look at this short example https://www.baeldung.com/retrofit it might help use refrofit with mapping json response into object the right way.

Comment: @CookieMonster have you checked my answer? If it did help you feel free to upvote and mark the question as a correct so we can let other people know that it works. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Map<String,List<YourObject>>` where `YourObject` contains the `id`, `type` and `value`.

So, response should be :

```
public class YourObject {
    public Map<String, NameDetail> nameDetail;
}

public class NameDetail {
    public int id;
    public int type;
    public String value;

}
```

And your service with `retrofit` should return :

`Call<YourObject> getStuff();`

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON structure is wrong. You should have something like this in order to get list of names:

```
{
"names" : [
  {
   "name": "name_1",
   "values": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": 1,
        "value": "25"
    },
     {
        "id": 2,
        "type": 2,
        "value": "25"
    }
   ]
  },
    {
    "name": "name_2",
   "values": [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "type": 1,
        "value": "25"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "type": 4,
        "value": "25"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "type": 4,
        "value": "25"
    }
    ]
  },
  {
   "name": "name_3",
   "values": [
    {
        "id": 8,
        "type": 1,
        "value": "25"
    }
    ]
  }
]}
```

Or if you can't affect server-side then use `HashMap<String,List<T>>` like Skizo-ozᴉʞS said but it would be the best to change the structure.

Comment: Yes, I did not say anything about JSON structure because sometimes you can not do anything to change it... but yes, if he would have that key would be easier :D